# Chart.js: For tooltips, can we achieve something like "only-when-not-intersect: true"? (Touchscreen hover/click conflict)

Tags: javascript, chart.js

In particular, is there a way to only trigger hover tips if we are NOT intersecting an element?

More background:
Trying to work out some touch screen compatibility issues. We have a custom onclick listener that renders a popup if we click on a data point; we also have a custom tooltip we render when we hover over the chart with `intersect` set to `false` currently. The issue is, on touch screens, if I click on a data point, both the tooltip and the popup shows up. I can use z-index and / or javascript in the onclick-listener to hide the tooltip, but both methods entail a slight delay: that is, the tooltip first shows for a split second, and then it's hidden. Is there any way to make this behave more elegantly? Thanks!

Edit:
Sorry for not being clear enough - this is particularly a question about Chart.js (v2), and to include some example:

```
const chartEl= document.getElementById('chartEl').getContext('2d');

[#chartEl is a canvas element: <canvas id="chartEl"></canvas>]

const justAChart = new Chart(chartEl, 
    {
      data: {
        datasets: someDataSet,
      },
      type: 'line',
      responsive: true,
      options: {
        hover: {
          mode: 'index',
          intersect: false
        },
        tooltips: {
          mode: 'index',
          intersect: false,
          // custom tooltip rendering
          custom: someCustomTooltip,
        }
      }
    };
);


// Onclick listener for popup when clicking on a datapoint
document.getElementById("chartEl").onclick = function(evt){
      let points = justAChart.getElementsAtEventForMode(evt, 'point', justAChart.options);
      if (points .length > 0) {
        showThePopup()
      }
    }
```

Comment: would this be a matter of `stopPropagation` or [useCapture](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)?

Comment: There are a lot of ways that the hover you're talking about could be happening. Is it using CSS `:hover` rules? Is it a JavaScript hover event? Et cetera... Perhaps you could add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows how your code works, to eliminate the guesswork?